# why is the steady state solution in a PDE problem time-independent?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

for instance let's consider the following I/BVP :

$$\begin{align}
u_t = u_{xx} \\
u|_{x=0} = U_0 \\ u|_{x=L} = U_L \\
u(x,t=0) = \phi(x)
\end{align} $$

I know how to solve this type of problem I just don't get it why we assume that the solution is of the form $u(x,t) = u_{ss}(x) + v(x,t)$

especially why is $u_{ss}$ time-independent ?

if someone can shed some light on this it'd be great.

thanks !

Comment: Well, the phrase “steady state” *means* a state which doesn't change with time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
u_t = u_{xx} \\
u|_{x=0} = U_0 \\ u|_{x=L} = U_L \\
u(x,t=0) = \phi(x)
\end{align} $$

''why we assume that the solution is of the form $u(x,t) = u_{ss}(x) + v(x,t).$'' We do this to reduce the inhomogeneous boundary conditions to homogeneous BCs to apply the method of seperation of variables. Since $u_{ss}$ satisfies $u_{xx}=0$ with the BCs $u_{ss}(0)=U_0$ and $u_{ss}(L)=U_L$, solving this we get $u_{ss}(x)=\frac{U_L-U_0}{L}x+U_0$. Using this and $u(x,t) = u_{ss}(x) + v(x,t)$ we have a BIVP for $v(x, t)$ with homogeneous boundary conditions: $$\begin{align}
v_t = v_{xx} \\
v|_{x=0} = 0 \\ v|_{x=L} = 0 \\
v(x,t=0) = \phi(x)-\frac{U_L-U_0}{L}x-U_0\qquad\text{(initial condition for}\, v)
\end{align} $$
Here $U_0$ and $U_L$ are assumed as constants.